# Inappropriate argument value (of correct type). An error occurred attempting to pass an argument to a function

Tags: python, jython, jes

For A class that I am taking I need to create a Collage using three images. Whenever I try and run the program I get an error.
"Inappropriate argument value (of the correct type).
An error occurred attempting to pass an argument to a function.
Please check line 26" I am confused as to what the issue is I have it written exactly the same for another image above this. But it dose not cause an error on that line. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 def createCollage():
  fileName1 = pickAFile()
  src1= makePicture(fileName1)
  print(src1)
  filename2= pickAFile()
  src2=makePicture(filename2)
  print(src2)
  filename3=pickAFile()
  src3=makePicture(filename3)
  print (src3)
  canvas=makeEmptyPicture(1300,1000)
  print canvas
  targetX=0
  for sourceX in range(0,getWidth(src3)):
    targetY=100
    for sourceY in range(0,getHeight(src3)):
      color=getColor(getPixel(src3,sourceX,sourceY))
      setColor(getPixel(canvas,targetX,targetY), color)
      targetY=targetY+1
    targetX=targetX+1
  targetX=650
  for sourceX in range(0,getWidth(src1)-100):
    targetY= 300
    for sourceY in range(0,getHeight(src1)-50):
      color=getColor(getPixel(src1,sourceX,sourceY))
      setColor(getPixel(canvas,targetX,targetY), color)
      targetY=targetY+1
    targetX=targetX+1
  targetX=600
  for sourceX in range(0,getWidth(src2)):
    targetY=430
    for sourceY in range(150,getHeight(src2)):
      color=getColor(getPixel(src2,sourceX,sourceY))
      setColor(getPixel(canvas,targetX,targetY), color)
      targetY=targetY+1
    targetX=targetX+1
  targetX=10
  for sourceX in range(20,getWidth(src2)-100):
    targetY=270
    for sourceY in range(0,getHeight(src2)-50):
      color=getColor(getPixel(src2,sourceX,sourceY))
      setColor(getPixel(canvas,targetX,targetY), color)
      targetY=targetY+1
    targetX=targetX+1
  targetX=50
  for sourceX in range(0,getWidth(src1)):
    targetY= 430
    for sourceY in range(120,getHeight(src1)):
      color=getColor(getPixel(src1,sourceX,sourceY))
      setColor(getPixel(canvas,targetX,targetY), color)
      targetY=targetY+1
    targetX=targetX+1
  show(src1)
  show(src2)
  show(src3)
  show(canvas)
  return canvas
  writePictureTo(canvas,("C:/Temp Python/CollagePic.png"))  
createCollage()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code and traceback error as text and not as an image.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I added the code and removed the picture sorry about that.

Comment: The earlier messages in the output in your image actually are useful, you should include all of that in the question. The actual error is actually described in more detail on the line before what you've quoted.

Comment: I see that now I am not sure how i over looked it completly thank you for pointing it out

Comment: It loads correctly now but dose not save a copy to the computer the way that its supposed to any thoughts on why the writePictureTo is not working? I am running JES in admin mode and have tired different file paths, saving as a different file type and replacing canvas with pic but so far nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Your `targetX` value is out of bounds. The `canvas` image is 1300 pixels wide, but when you get the error, you're passing in `x=1300`, which doesn't work with zero indexing. The range of valid pixel x-coordinates is 0-1299.